# Proof of $(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)=(A-B)\cup(B-A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, solution-verification

I was trying to prove $(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)=(A-B)\cup(B-A)$ and came across issues in translating (pertaining to what I did with $\emptyset$) and got through the proof but was doubting its accuracy so if someone could please affirm or deny its accuracy that would be great. Also, I'm guessing there's much shorter ways of proving this and was thinking of what those ways might be and all I could come up with was set construction. Any ideas on others?

**My proof is as follows:**

Suppose $x\in(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)$.

Thus $x\in(A\cup B):x\notin(A\cap B)$.

Hence $x\in A$ or $x\in B:x\notin A$ or $x\notin B$.

This presents us with 4 cases:

1. $x\in A:x\notin A$
2. $x\in A:x\notin B$
3. $x\in B:x\notin A$
4. $x\in B:x\notin B$

Case 1 and 4 are $\emptyset$ however so we really have $x\in\emptyset$, or $x\in A:x\notin B$, or $x\in B:x\notin A$, or $x\in\emptyset$ which is equivalent to
$x\in\emptyset$, or $x\in(A-B)$, or $x\in(B-A)$, or $x\in\emptyset$.
Which is the same as $x\in\emptyset\cup(A-B)\cup(B-A)\cup\emptyset$
And since the union of the empty set with any set X is the set X itself, we have $x\in(A-B)\cup(B-A)$, which shows that $\forall x[x\in(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)\Rightarrow x\in(A-B)\cup(B-A)]$.

Alternatively, suppose that $x\in(A-B)\cup(B-A)$. Since the union of any set X is the set X itself, we can say that $x\in\emptyset_1\cup(A-B)\cup(B-A)\cup\emptyset_2$ where $\emptyset_1={x\in A:x\notin A}$ and $\emptyset_2={x\in B:x\notin B}$ so $x\in\emptyset_1$, or $x\in(A-B)$, or $x\in(B-A)$, or $x\in\emptyset_2$, thus $x\in [x\in A:x\notin A] $, or $x\in A:x\notin B$, or $x\in B:x\notin A$, or $x\in B:x\notin B$, hence $x\in A:x\notin A$, or $x\in A:x\notin B$, or $x\in B:x\notin A$, or $x\in B:x\notin B$, therefore $x\in A$ or $x\in B$, and $x\notin A$ or $x\notin B$ such that $x\in(A\cup B)$ and $x\notin(A\cap B)$ which means that $x\in(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)$.

The former shows that $\forall x[x\in(A-B)\cup(B-A)\Rightarrow x\in(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)]$
, and thus $(A-B)\cup(B-A)\subset(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)$ by the definition of a subset.

Since, as we showed earlier, $(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)\subset(A-B)\cup(B-A)$ and $(A-B)\cup(B-A)\subset(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)$, by the definition of set equality, $(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)=(A-B)\cup(B-A)$.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you look at how this was formatting before posting?

Comment: Yes. I thought I finally had it this time. I'm not a computer guy and am slow to learn how to "write math" on this site. I'm currently trying to fix it though. I apologize. The first quarter or so should be readable now

Comment: What does a sentence such as "Thus $x\in(A\cup B):x\notin(A\cap B)$" mean? That is not a standard use of the colon, and it is difficult to guess at a meaning for it that makes sense for all of the colons in your text.

Comment: It means "such that". I know it's not used by everyone but I thought it was relatively conventional. My apologies is that isn't the case.

Comment: I was trying to edit your post and thus hopefully offer some help, but I surrendered. Your formatting is a disaster. Moreover, you are making many nonsensical statements (which makes the editing even more difficult).

Comment: Well it's certainly not impossible because I just did it, but thanks for sharing that critical piece of information

Comment: @LiamCooney Please ignore anyone that is complaining about your style.  I understand you're still a beginner.  I'll help you fix it, just give me a minute.

Comment: Thank you. It think I just fixed it all though. It looks "normal" to me now. And I pressed submit or whatever...is it still not looking how it should?

Comment: @LiamCooney I edited it.  If you press "enter" just once to break your line, in the output you don't see a line break.  You have to press "enter" twice (i.e., input two line breaks in your code) to see one line break in the output.  I just think my edit looks a little neater, but I didn't change any of your content.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. It also probably doesn't help that I'm often doing this on my phone opposed to a computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It means "such that". I know it's not used by everyone but I thought it was relatively conventional. My apologies is that isn't the case.

It's not *quite* used this way.   The convention is used in **set construction** notation to separate the domain of the bound variable and the predicate that constructs the set.   In set construction, we may also use pipes ("|") for this.

For example : $\;2\Bbb N= \{x \in \Bbb N : \exists k\in \Bbb N \; (x=2k)\}\;$, reads as: "the set $2\Bbb N$ is the set of natural numbers, $x$, such that there exists a natural number, $k$ so that $x=2k$."

Thusly, what you appear to be trying to say is:

$$\begin{align} &(A\cup B)-(A\cap B) \; 
\\[1ex] = &  \{ x\in A\cup B: x\notin A\cap B\}
\\[1ex]  & \vdots
\\[1ex] = & \{x\in A:x\notin B\}\cup\{x\in B:x\notin A\}
\\[1ex] = & (A-B)\cup (B-A)
\end{align}$$

Which is *okay*.

---

To use my words:

> Take an arbitrary element of the union of $A$ and $B$ that is not in their intersection, that is $\;(A\cup B)-(A \cap B)\;$.  This element is in either $A$ or in $B$ but it is not in both $A$ and $B$.   Considering case by case, (1) if it is in $A$, then it is not in $B$, and (2) if it is in $B$, then it is not in $A$.   So it is either in $A$ but not $B$ or it is in $B$ but not $A$.   Which is to say it is in the symmetric difference of the sets. $$(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)\subseteq (A-B)\cup(B-A)$$
>
> Take any arbitrary element of the union of set differences that is $(A-B)\cup(B-A)$.   This element is either in $A$ but not $B$, or it is in $B$ but not $A$.   Hence it is in either $A$ or $B$ but it is not in both. $$(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)\supseteq (A-B)\cup(B-A)$$
>
> Hence the two are demonstrably equivalent, which is what was to be shown. $$(A\cup B)-(A\cap B) \equiv (A-B)\cup(B-A) \quad \Box$$

Comment: Thank you. So when I see that though it looks exactly like what I wrote. I'm guessing the difference then is that you have what I wrote in {} thus indicating its a set which allows us to use that notation

Comment: Thank you! What I'm not sure people are realizing though (perhaps people are just skimming over my proof and not reading it thoroughly due to its verbosity and length or maybe I'm just missing something here) is that I feel like I basically did what you just did EXCEPT I noticed that where you said there were 2 cases, I said there were 4 with $x\in A$ such that $x\notin A$ and $x\in B$ such that $x\notin B$. And that's why my proof got really long; I considered the 2 other two cases which were the empty set.

Comment: So, is the vibe I'm getting then just that my proof wasn't wrong but my consideration of the other 2 cases which were the empty set unnecessary but my proof wasn't technically wrong. Or was it wrong DUE to my dealings with the empty set? I'd really like to get to the bottom of this. I made a similar comment on another answer to this question. Please tell me if I'm not being clear

Comment: @LiamCooney Indeed, your argument was not *technically* wrong, but rather just unnecessarily cluttered and in a non-standard format.  You have the concept down okay; so you just need to work on the presentation and streamline it a bit.

Comment: My therapist would like you; story of my life. That's very helpful though, thank you. I think part of it is that I took an intro to proof class last semester which was my first thing of that sort and the professor was MUCH more detailed than you guys are in the proofs (which I need to carefully consider because I know most people at UNH considered what he did to be "soft analysis". But basically he didn't want us leaving any logical gaps so I think I've just taken after his style of proofing, but I'm guessing my statements regarding "for every x..." could be taken out along with my summations?

Comment: And the stuff about the empty set (cases 3&4) can just be ignored?

Comment: @LiamCooney Well, not so much *ignored* as *easily dismissed*, but yes.  If an element of a set exists, it is not in the empty set. So you only have to explore the cases that are not the empty set (or at least those that are not clearly the empty set).

Comment: @LiamCooney  Still, there is nothing at all wrong with "*displaying even the most obvious steps, for clarity's sake*".  It can even be helpful! (Most especially in an exam.)  Just try not to hide the forest with too many trees.

Comment: Hahaha perfect! This has been very helpful; I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ be in $A \cup B$. Then either $x \in A$ and $x \not \in B$, $x \in A$ and $x \in B$, or $x\not \in A$ and $x \in B$.

Therefore, if $x$ is in $A \cup B$ but not in $A \cap B$, then $x$ is in $A - B$ or $B-A$. Vice versa, if $x$ is in $A - B$ or $B-A$, then $x$ is in $A \cup B$ but not in $A \cap B$.

I'll let you finish the proof (it only involves one sentence).

**Note:** it's normal to struggle with those kind of proofs at first. Draw diagrams and work hard until you really understand what is going on.

Comment: Thank you. I see the logic here and can certainly appreciate its brevity, but I'm just a little hesitant to personally use this because I'm new to proofing and while I follow what you're saying and it makes sense to me, I likely wouldn't be able to recreate it because I don't see the logical "flow" to it (not the proofs problem but mine). For example, I'm not exactly sure what the last sentence you speak of would be. "Vice versa" I'm guessing you say to take care of the proof going in "the other direction" so would it just be that each set is then a subset of the other?

Comment: You should not use this. You should try to understand the idea, and then write your own (similar) proof, with the appropriate amount of details. Drawing a « Venn diagram » will also help.

Comment: I usually start my reading it to myself and verifying it to myself logically without a proof. Then sometimes I also do a Venn Diagram especially if I don't immediately see the truth of it. I think that making the Venn diagrams can be a good tool, but I don't personally see how they aid in proof writing.

Comment: I think you understood it right. Saying « vice versa » is often a bit ambiguous. I updated my answer.

Comment: When you draw the Venn diagram of $A \cup B$, you can see three « sections » appearing. The idea here is to decompose $A \cup B$ into those three disjoint sets.

Comment: Yep! That's what I was saying. Thanks.

Comment: Also, not to be a nitpick, but is my proof above technically wrong though? I can't find anything wrong with it. I know it's long and verbose but this is pretty much how I learned to proof

Comment: You make multiple nonsensical statements. A rewriting of the proof might be correct.

Comment: Did you read it or skim it? I only ask because I just retread it (fixed only 1 or 2 things that I thought could lead to ambiguity) but overall I thought it made sense. What did you think was "nonsensical"?. If you skimmed over it I could see how the stuff I said about $\emptyset$ would appear nonsensical but if you read it on whole I think those things make sense, but if they're not true then my proof is wrong. I don't know if that means the same thing as "nonsensical" though...

Comment: I didn't mean wrong. The accepted answer talks about your use of « such that », which is the main problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different understanding:
$$\begin{align*}
(A \cup B) - (A \cap B) &= (A \cup B) \cap (A \cap B)^c \\
&= (A \cup B) \cap (A^c \cup B^c) \quad (1)\\
&= (A \cap B^c) \cup (B \cap A^c) \quad (2) \\
&=(A-B) \cup (B-A)
\end{align*}$$

If you need help understanding how to get from $(1) \to (2)$, let me know.
*Hint:* It follows from $A \cap (B \cup C) = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)$.

Comment: No, I understand your translations, thank you. The one I used is just more intuitive to me I guess. I tried doing using the translation you used instead but it got me to the same place. I'd like to point out though that, I basically did the same thing you did here EXCEPT using the other translation AND (although, as I said, I used your translation and got to the same place) I added the 2 other cases that you did not (in your proof, going from line 3-4) which was where I got the empty set stuff. So are you basically telling me that what I did with the empty set was just unnecessary?

Comment: Or if it's just plain wrong id appreciate knowing that as well. Please tell me if you don't understand my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way to do it by algebra
\begin{align}
(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)
&=(A-A\cap B)\cup(B-A\cap B)
\\
&=(A-B)\cup(B-A)
\end{align}

Comment: I was trying to let him get the intermediate steps on his own...

Comment: I did not see your post when I submit mine. Sorry about it.

Comment: Aha! Thank you. So what I was struggling with was the empty sets. I don't see how this is really any different than what I though except for the fact that I added a lot of detail; yours is obviously more succinct. Question though: is what you wrote a proof? Like can you just show equivalency like that or was this just an outline and you still have to suppose x belongs to some set like I did and all? This is obviously shorter because you didn't do that and you only went in one direction. I'm assuming you can do that because you showed equivalency instead of one set being a subset of another.